# Mesh Has Different Shape in Object and Edit Modes

Tags: mesh, materials, edit-mode, object-mode

I made a mesh and applied a material (skin colour) to it. But now when I try to edit the mesh, the changes are not being reflected in object mode.

As you can see in this clip, the neck seems thicker in object mode when it should look like that in edit mode

[image: Notice the neck]

What can be done to make the neck thinner in object mode? I've even tried removing the materials but to no avail.

Comment: An image of the modifiers used here could be helpful

Comment: @Tejas Edited the screen capture. Was that what you meant?

Comment: Does your mesh have any shape keys?

Comment: @Brenticus Yes it did. I removed it and the object mode looks proper now. Please post this as an answer so I can select it. Thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mesh might have a shape key. If you have shape keys all of the edits you make in edit mode could be stored in the shape key. Removing the shape key if you don't need it would be the easiest solution.